# Create dynamic control file in java from template

Tags: java, xml, template-engine

I need to create a control-file (for SQLLoader) depending on some variables (filename, bad-filename, table to load into, etc).

Right now I have a method in java that creates the file and works fine. My problem comes when I have to modify the structure of that control file. I need to change that in java source code, compile, undeploy previous app, deploy the new one, just to change that control's file structure.

I was wondering if there is a way to make a template where I just pass the variables (mentioned above) but outside java, let's say some kind of xml or something, so I just change that "template" and voilà my app just fill in the variables.

Answer (score 0):

In one of our applications we generate the control file from code (in our case C#, but that doesn't matter)
Create the file from a template (outside of your app), fill in the variables and have your application copy it to the place where SQLLoader expects it.
Only thing you need is for your java app to have permission to write to that directory.

If it is a Java web application this is a little tricky, as writing files from the webapp can introduce a security risk

Comment: But how to create that template? What tool can I use? This is a webapp but just the application-server is the one generating the file.

Comment: How can I create that template? Is there a java library that takes a File as input and replaces some strings? Let's say that I have my template control file so I read it and then replace the string `replaceThis` with the correct parameter.